# Can not download any widget from KDE store

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am trying to download widgets from KDE store.

The widget page load very slowly.

Download button or any other plasmoid button give error 404.

Let me give an example with [netspeed widget](https://store.kde.org/p/998895/).

When I click download button, it goes to the following link.

https://store.kde.org/p/998895/startdownload?file_id=1533574869&file_name=netspeed-widget-1.5.plasmoid&file_type=application/zip&file_size=13273&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.opendesktop.org%2Fapi%2Ffiles%2Fdownload%2Fid%2F1533574869%2Fs%2F1cbcc87eba331a20c19288fdb57368bf%2Ft%2F1539534015%2Fu%2F%2Fnetspeed-widget-1.5.plasmoid

Then it redirect to the following link.

https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1533574869/s/1cbcc87eba331a20c19288fdb57368bf/t/1539534015/u//netspeed-widget-1.5.plasmoid

Then it shows the following error.

```
This dl.opendesktop.org page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1533574869/s/1cbcc87eba331a20c19288fdb57368bf/t/1539534015/u//netspeed-widget-1.5.plasmoid
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I have no problem with my internet. As you can see, I am asking this question.
Not behind a proxy.
Needless to say can not install widgets from the panel as well. They give the famous provider.xml  error.

```
Loading of providers from file: http://download.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml failed.
```

Comment: I too can't reach store.kde.org. Maybe you could try later?

Comment: store.kde.org is live again, so this question is not reproducible.